# How to implement this parenDist with O(log²n) span

Tags: algorithm, sml

> Implement a function
>
> ```
> val parenPairs : Paren.t Seq.t ! (int * int) Seq.t
> ```
>
> where (`parenPairs S`) returns a sequence of index-pairs where each
>   pair contains the index of a parenthesis as well as its matching
>   partner. For example the input `(())()` should yield some permutation
>   of `<(0, 3), (4, 5), (1, 2)>`. Your implementation should have
>   `O(|S|log|S|)` work and `O(log^2|S|)` span.
>
> Hint: try marking each parenthesis with how many other parentheses are
>   enclosing it. You might also need to sort at some point...

I can only come up with using stack to solve it, but if so, it will cost `O(|S|)` Work and `O(|S|)` Span which means there is no parallelism. So how to implement this function with `O(|S|log|S|)` Work and `O(log²|S|)` Span?

By the way, this exersice is in a recitation about `scan`(or parallel `iter`).

my implementation as below(0 stands for '(' and 1 stands for ')')

`t` is a list stack and `i` records current index. When `x=1` and the top of stack is `0`, it means parenMatch so I insert `nm=(hd t, i)` into the result list `l`.

Obviously, this implementation has no parallelism. T^T

```
fun parenPairs (parens : int list) =
  let 
    fun pd (_,_,l) [] = l 
      | pd (t,i,l) (x::xs) = 
      if x = 0 then pd (i::t,i+1,l) xs
      else (*x=1*)
        if null t then pd (t,i+1,l) xs
        else let 
             val nm = (hd t, i)
             in pd (tl t,i+1, nm::l) xs end
  in pd ([],0,[]) parens

  end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you have an attempted implementation or pseudocode that you have a specific problem with?

Comment: Hi there, please remove the image link and post the text/code here directly. The community doesn't appreciate images or links to images.

Comment: @sammy  Sorry, I am a green hand in Stack Overflow. And thanks for  your remind.

Comment: @spiCY: You say "*O(|S|)* work and *O(|S|)* span which means there is no parallelism", but what do you mean by that? What parallelism? Technically, an algorithm that is *O(|S|)* **is also** *O(|S| log |S|)* since this describes an upper bound. (The assignment probably means [*θ(|S| log |S|)*](https://medium.com/@.RT/total-n00bs-guide-to-big-o-big-%CF%89-big-%CE%B8-aa259ae8a1c2).)

Comment: @Simon 'Reinstate Monica' Shine: That's just what I want to know. Gernally using stack to solve a problrm means the algorithm is sequential. And as you see, the work of my implementation is same as span. So I say it has no parallelism.